# Unpack lists of variable length using an iterator

Tags: python, python-2.7

In **Python 2.7**, I have a generator that receives lists of `x,y` coordinates and unpacks them.

However, sometimes the list contains more than just the `x,y`. Sometimes it is `x,y,z` and some other time `x,y,z,m`

```
xy_coords = [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]]
xyz_coords = [[0,0,0], [1,1,1], [2,2,2]]
xyzm_coords = [[0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2]]

def unpack_coords(coords):
    iterator = iter(coords)
    x, y = iterator.next()
    yield x
    yield y
```

When the coords contains more than 2 values, I have `ValueError too many values to unpack`.

Is there a way to handle all possible cases in order to yield only the `x` and `y`. The `z` and `m` values can be ignored.

Comment: `x, y = iterator.next()[:2]` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply slice off the first two values, provided the type of `iterator.next()` is a `list` or a `tuple`

```
x, y = iterator.next()[:2]
```

Comment: Actually if `.next()` returns anything that is sliceable (`deque`, `array.array`, etc.)